# Table displaying real time data

Tags: asp.net, ajax, gridview, real-time

So essentially I have an ASP .NET application with the code behind running a for loop which calls a web service, every time the loop completes data is added to a datatable and then databound to a gridview at the end of the loop.

What i am trying to achieve is a table which updates as the data comes in.

I know I cant use a update panels as they dont update till the for loop is complete.
I know AJAX is the where im heading but my code behind is all in VB. 
I have also looked into using the jquery plugin Datatables but Im not sure if its possible to update in "real time"

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Are you seeking REAL Real-time data?  I can build you a quick demo and show you how to make this instantly deliver to your client in less than 100ms typical.  If you are using JavaScript consider the JS SDK - https://github.com/pubnub/javascript

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is in fact only possible through AJAX. Therefor, what you need to do  is in your code-behind no do the for-loop but just bind your data to the table.

Then on the client-side, with Javascript you could kick off a timer that periodically asks new data from the server. Then through AJAX you get a new set of data and you append it to the table.

Comment: Im now thinking the following: - turn my function into a webmethod() , On my client side I will have a javascript for loop as the idea is the web service im using is called as many times as the user wants - then inside the for loop I will use jquery ajax like the following

Comment: function asyncServerCall(param1,param2) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: 'Default.aspx/MyFunction',
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify({ param1: param1, param1: param }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    Add data.d to Html table
                }

            });
        }

Would that work?

Comment: This will still only make one call. What you need to do is put the for loop in Javascript (not an actual for-loop, just a timer), that periodically polls for new data

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am a little late, but this is how I created an html table for displaying real time data. If you can use Session, then you can initialize a counter on the client side or server side and store/update the value in session. You can then configure your ajax call to get rows for your table one at a time. A javascript append method can be used to add row which you receive from ajax, during runtime, and once a row has been added, you can increment the counter. jQuery datatable plugin does provide the feature with real time update. However, you will have to tweak the javascript a little, or call the .Datatables() method for each row added, which will make it inefficient. I would recommend a generic html table with some CSS styles. Good luck!